# CentOS 7 -> find: missing Argument for "-exec"

Tags: linux, centos

Disclaimer: I am a total Linux amateur.
Hi, I am currently setting up a PHPIPAM Server on CentOS 7.  I am following this guide: https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-phpipam-on-centos-7/ , which tells me to run the command: "

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} ;
```

When I do so, the message:

> find: missing argument for "-exec".

shows up.
What can I do to get the command to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordinarily the `;` acts as a separator between commands. However, for `find -exec` it needs to be provided as an actual parameter to the command itself (to indicate where the -exec option ends). To achieve that, it needs to be either quoted or escaped:

```
-exec ..... \;

-exec ..... ";"

-exec ..... ';'
```

Comment: He's missing the `f` as well. See my answer.

Comment: The `f` was present in the example found in the original website, while the `;` escape/quoting is missing there as well.

Comment: I think this worked. No error message. How can I check if it worked?

Comment: Well, a possible approach would be: 1) Look at the command you told `find` to run (which is "chmod 0644 <all files>"). 2) Figure out what the command does (it sets permissions 0644, aka `rw-r--r--`, for all files specified). 3) Use `ls -l` to look at the files and verify that they indeed have the permissions that chmod was supposed to set.

Comment: You can also use `find . -type f -ls` to list all files with permissions, or `find . -type f \( \! -perm 0644 \) -ls` to find those which have unexpected permissions set. Or... you could run the original command again, but change `chmod` to `chmod -v` and make it verbose about what it's actually _doing._

Comment: Ok, I tried these. Looks like it worked just fine, thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, I would tend to use `+` instead of `;` in this situation so `find` can put multiple files into a single command line to execute.  Then, `+` wouldn't need the quoting that `;` does.

Answer (score 5):

#### When I do so, the message: 'find: missing argument for "-exec".' shows up

> ```
> find . -type -exec chmod 0644 {} ;
> ```

You are missing a `\` before the `;` at the end of the line (which is missing in the link you quoted).

In addition, you haven't supplied an argument for `-type`.

Your command should be:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

> `-type c` File is of type c as listed below:
>
> `b` block (buffered) special
>
> `c` character (unbuffered) special
>
> `d` directory
>
> `p` named pipe (FIFO)
>
> `f` regular file
>
> `l` symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is broken. If you want to search for symbolic links when -L is in effect, use `-xtype.`
>
> `s` socket
>
> `D` door (Solaris)

Source [find Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html)

Comment: Yes i forgot to write down the 'f' in here, I did write it in the command though. So that is not the problem, thank you anyway. The solution with either \;  ';' or ";" seemed to work.

Comment: @FranzZehrer If you copied incorrectly, you should edit the question to show what you actually did.

Comment: It should have been obvious that this was a copying error. If he actually ran the command as posted, he would have gotten an error about in incorrect argument to `-type`, not a missing argument to `-exec`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain why the problem is happening, but there is another solution to the problem. You can use `+` instead of `\;` and then you don't have to worry about escaping the `;`. For something like `chmod` over a large number of files, this will likely be somewhat faster, too. You would run it like this:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

They're not exactly identical, though. With `+` the `find` command is passing multiple files as separate arguments to a single invocation of `chmod`. A lot of programs can handle this just fine, but some can't. If a program you want to pass to `-exec` needs to take exactly 1 file argument at a time, then you have to use `\;` instead.

Comment: In addition, with `+` the `{}` must appear exactly once and be the last argument (i.e. just before `+`); while with `;` it can be anywhere, many times or none. At least this is what POSIX says, some implementations of `find` may be more flexible.